Whether the solution of $\Delta u=f$ belong to $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$?
Assume that and $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz open bounded set , or pipe-like area such as $\{(x_1,x_2):-\infty < x_1 < +\infty, a\le x_2 \le b\}$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$. $f \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$, consider following Dirichlet boundary problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\Delta u=f \quad {\rm in} \,\, \Omega
\\
u=0 \quad {\rm on} \,\, \partial\Omega
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Then by the classcal Pde theory, we can solve this problem in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, and by inprove the regularity of $\partial \Omega$, we can improve the regularity of $u$ from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ to higher.
My question is: whether the solution $u$ has a compact support in $\Omega$? So that by improve the regularity of $\partial \Omega$, we can get a $u\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ also. If not, does such a problem have a counterexample?
Or point out any issues or inadequacies in my statement.

In general $u$ does not have compact support in $\Omega$ even if $f$ is smooth with compact support. Here is an example:
Let $\Omega = (-1,1)$ and let $u$ be a function such that
$$
u(x) = 1- |x| 
$$ for $|x|\ge\epsilon$. No matter how one extend $u$ smoothly to the interval $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$, the support of $u$ will be $\Omega$ while the support of $\Delta u$ will be $[-\epsilon,+\epsilon]$ at most.

An extreme example would be $v = 1-|x|$ which is the solution of $-v''= \delta_0$. Then $f$ has very small support, but the support of $v$ is the whole $\Omega$. Smearing out $f$ (ie. smoothing it) gives $f$ with small support but a solution with support in the whole domain.

Thank you very much! You give a counterexample in one dimension. I post this problem in ${\mathbb R}^2$, when in ${\mathbb R}^2$ and take $\Omega=B_0(1)$, and also $u(x)=1-|x|$ for $|x|\ge \epsilon$, we have $\Delta u(x)=-\frac{1}{|x|}, \epsilon \le |x| \le 1$, which is not zero when $\epsilon \le |x| \le 1$, is there any counterexample in ${\mathbb R}^2$?

In $\mathbb R^2$ you can take $u(x) = \log(|x|)$ for $|x|\in (\epsilon,1)$, then extend smoothly.

Thanks！ You help me a lot.
